# How to monitor API requests by user / connected app?

Tags: api, logging, monitoring

We have clients that access Salesforce API to write data and read data using the salesforce standard APIs. How do monitor the traffic, logs for these API calls? I'm also looking for ways to know the traffic by username or clientId (connected app).

Comment: did you look into Event Monitoring? A OOTB extra cost SFDC feature

Comment: Yes, but the 24hrs time period may not work. I need to look at the hourly log, but even that may not help much with our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Winter 20 announces [near real time Event Monitoring](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_security_em_rtem_ga.htm) and this includes [ApiEvents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm) and [UriEvents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_uri.htm)

In both event types, you have access to the URI, client IP address, and SFDC UserID of the running user (among other fields such as statistics on run time)

> Available to customers who purchased a Salesforce Shield or Salesforce Event Monitoring add-on subscription. To view or manage events, enable the View Data Leakage Detection Events user permission.